# How could i limit the number of stargates?

Tags: technology

In my universe the galaxy is stripped clean of most life and surface minerals on planets by massive alien swarms numbered in the trillions. Earth had colonized our solar system and a few others by reverse-engineering jump drives found on Mars. (Battlestar Galactica style)
To escape the swarm, we installed jump drives on the our space stations and habitats, jumping from star to star for thousands of years until the swarm move on to another galaxy.

We figured how to build large stargates capable of generating a stable wormhole to another gate during our time on the move. Now that the alien swarm is gone, some groups are looking to settle down again in rare cluster that are not fully striped of natural resources.

How do I limit the amount of stargates that can be constructed? Can only be made around specific type of stars, rare material, range etc.
I need them to connect fifty or so systems in regions throughout the galaxy but no connections between the regions.

Stations/habitats can only jump 250ly per day. Capital ships cam only jump 60ly per day, with a 10ly max range, so 6 jumps per day.

Comment: Is there a reason why the answers you've provided in your question are not suitable?  Why is a limitation by rare materials and/or by range of a stargate not the answer?  I feel like this question may need more clarification.

Comment: with rare materials I think it would only be a matter of time until they find enough to link all the regions .. range of the stargate am not sure if there are clusters of stars with no other stars say within 30 ly of them ??

Comment: I'm confused. Why can stations, which are usually considered so big that they're practically immobile, jump faster than capital ships?

Comment: I'm curious as to the nature of these alien "swarms".  "Trillions" is not that much when measured against the scale of a galaxy.

Comment: Given that you state in the question that answers as diverse as "Only around specific stars" "Requires rare materials" and "Has limited range" are all valid, this question definitely runs fowl of our prohibition on questions with many valid answers. We're not a brainstorming site. If you take the [tour] or visit the [help] you'll see that we work differently than other Q&A sites and place restrictions not only on the topics that can be discussed but the form of the questions that can be asked about those topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple distance effect**

The amount of matter in the galaxy and its distribution throughout the galaxy leads to gravitational/quantum technobabble effects on a wormhole (WH) as it is generated. Basically the greater the distance between two gates the more 'gravitational' related stress effects start to impact the stability and accuracy of the WH.

Your WH is like a stick of licorice linking two points in space/time and you the user have to get it to 'whip' across the gap in space time to the other gate. Once you do that the tip is fixed/locked in place and the bridge is established & stabilized. However the longer the stick of licorice has to be the greater the chance it will 'snap' under the gravitational stresses and strains of supporting its own mass/structure and because the strain is worst at the far 'tip' of the WH the harder it also becomes to hit the target (the other gate).

**This leads to two big problems.**

Firstly the WHs are power hogs to create at large sizes but once stabilized by connecting at the other gate require little power to maintain. So its enormously wasteful to generate repeated wormholes only to have them fail. Secondly there's a non-zero chance that a collapsing WH from a failed lock will release some of the energy used to create it back into the generating gate at your end. If this happens it poses certain critical 'life challenges' for the gate operators and the facility its housed in.

**Conclusion**

Fear not though, experimentation and research has long ago revealed a maximum safe distance (plus or minus a few LY) for gates depending on  local galactic mass distribution etc. Some gate clusters might be able to extend a little father safely than others for that reason - you choose. The bonus of this idea is that in an emergency someone might risk trying for a gate farther away than normal but since the risks of failure go up exponentially with distance the further you exceed local safety limits the greater the danger/probability of a collapse becomes.

As a side note the same galactic mass distribution that limits WHs contributes to the limits you've identified for your jump drives i.e. try to jump too far or too close to dense extra solar objects etc and your ship comes out the other side as a stream of sub atomic particles.

Answer (score 5):

- Operating stargates emit technobabble radiation which interferes with the tuning of other stargates nearby. The effect is cumulative, and falls off sharply with distance. One stargate was found on Mars, one new gate was assembled at Lagrange-5, and a bunch of stations went through that one gate. At the destination, far enough away, a new gate could be assembled and tuned, a process taking days or weeks, before the next step out.
- There is a relation between range, diameter, and energy. When a gate is built, the design of the mechanism determines range and diameter within 10% or so. Truly short-range gates are too small to send people. If a ship wants to go a shorter distance, it has to jump twice (once out and once back).

Answer (score 0):

**Swarm directly targeted materials needed for the building of the gates**

There is only [enter your number] systems left that still has the material.

It is also jump-volatile so transporting it using the jump drives make it loose its properties.